# How to change the list separator in python?

Tags: python

I have a list

```
[u'Scanned by CamS\nINCOME TAN DEPARTMENT\nINDER SINGH\nAMAR JEETSINGH FIORA\n2407/1985\nMimi\nAAPPF5793,\nGOVT of INDIA\n']
```

is there a way to change the list separator from `'\n'` to `','` using python?

My expected output is

```
['Scanned by CamS','INCOME TAN DEPARTMENT','INDER SINGH','AMAR JEETSINGH FIORA','2407/1985','Mimi','AAPPF5793,','GOVT of INDIA']
```

This is fake PAN.

Comment: Isn't that a string and not a list in your 1st example?..

Comment: I had checked the type it is showing me as list.

Comment: Yes, it is a list containing one string.

Comment: You can use the string `.split` method to create a list from that Unicode string. Please see the docs for details.

Comment: @DipanwitaDas - Please tell me that is a *fake* PAN number you just displayed publicly!

Comment: yes this is a fake PAN

Comment: You can try it split,replace and also with regex

Answer (score 2):

using `split` on first list item (desired string) :

```
l = [u'Scanned by CamS\nINCOME TAN DEPARTMENT\nINDER SINGH\nAMAR JEETSINGH FIORA\n2407/1985\nMimi\nAAPPF5793,\nGOVT of INDIA\n']
l =  l[0].split('\n')
l # ['Scanned by CamS', 'INCOME TAN DEPARTMENT', 'INDER SINGH', 'AMAR JEETSINGH FIORA', '2407/1985', 'Mimi', 'AAPPF5793,', 'GOVT of INDIA', '']
```

last element is empty because of last `'\n'`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this both..

```
a = [u'Scanned by CamS\nINCOME TAN DEPARTMENT\nINDER SINGH\nAMAR JEETSINGH FIORA\n2407/1985\nMimi\nAAPPF5793,\nGOVT of INDIA\n']

print str(a[0]).split('\n')
#['Scanned by CamS', 'INCOME TAN DEPARTMENT', 'INDER SINGH', 'AMAR JEETSINGH FIORA', '2407/1985', 'Mimi', 'AAPPF5793,', 'GOVT of INDIA', '']

print str(a[0]).replace('\n',' ,')
#Scanned by CamS ,INCOME TAN DEPARTMENT ,INDER SINGH ,AMAR JEETSINGH FIORA ,2407/1985 ,Mimi ,AAPPF5793, ,GOVT of INDIA ,
```

Comment: The first part of the answer does not need a call to `str()`. The second part of the answer is wrong: it does not produce a list of strings as requested by OP.

Comment: @DYZ For 1st part I kept it as pure string rather than  unicode . And in the 2nd part I just gave him other way to do it. He can append in a list.